# How can I insert a non-self-closing element in another element?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to insert some `<wbr>` elements in a run of text. Cutting some complicated code out, here's the crux:

```
// ... pos contains position of hyphen etc.

brokenTokens.Add(new XText(token.Substring(0, pos)));
brokenTokens.Add(new XElement("wbr"));
brokenTokens.Add(new XText(token.Substring(pos)));

XElement e = new XElement(originalElement.Name, brokenTokens);
```

Except that it yields:

```
<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">This is some really long, super<wbr xmlns="" />-hypenated text.</p>
```

I can probably figure out how to kill that nasty empty namespace declaration but how can I make it `<wbr>` and not `<wbr />`?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. XML != HTML

Comment: This was my fear. Now where did I put my drawing-`<wbr>`board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML either allows

```
<wbr/>
```

which is achieved by

```
var element = new XElement("wbr");
```

or

```
<wbr></wbr>
```

done by

```
var element = new XElement("wbr", string.Empty);
```

Since you're using XHTML, I even think using a HTML tag like `<wbr>` would not be compliant to the XHTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

You're working on XML: a solution would be to give `<wbr>` content. Otherwise, you have to be satisfied with the self-closing element (which is syntactically correct).

Answer (score 1):

You can give the wbr element the same namespace as its parent. The namespace will not be printed in that case.

Comment: Not the answer to the question but useful nonetheless.